SUMIFS matching a few range of values
I'm trying to calculate the value by keywords, regardless of their location in the text.
Text field contains different combinations of keywords (at the beginning, in the middle, at the end, etc).
Trying to receive the sum of values based on the keyword, but there are some other words that match a similar condition.
Here is an example - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T7pZoj1hvotzUFyvfjm7M-8rSJBlOI9MkzSYrQr1bH8/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I'm trying to use the sum of different SUMIFS(), but this formula should be changed in case another combination is added: =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"criteria 1",B:B,"AU")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"criteria 1",B:B," AU *")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"criteria 1",B:B,"AU *")
What is the best way to use SUMIFS() with REGEXMATCH to include only the necessary combination of keywords?


Here's one approach which you may adapt accordingly:
=sumif(index(--regexmatch(B:B,"\bAU\b")),1,C:C)


Regex - \b

